# Can intellij be set to automatically "Download Sources and Documentation"

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

I seem to have to maunally click "Download Sources and Documentation" after each clean install, is there a way to get this to happen by default?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is also a setting on the *Import Project/Module* screen, or available via settings under *Maven > Importing*: *Automatically download sources/documentation*

If you want to change this setting across all projects change the above option in *File > Other Settings > Default Settings*

Comment: Couldn't find the "Other Settings", but there is _Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Importing > Automatically Download_

Comment: In 2023 look under File -> New projects setup -> Settings for new projects

Answer (score 3):

Intellij is ultimately using maven to download sources and documentation. So you need to configure maven.

Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs

So your sources and javadocs will be automatically downloaded whenever you do clean install.

Comment: even when it's eg gradle project?